# Gradle filter standard streams

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I'm currently using the following lines in my build.gradle:

```
test {
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
}
```

together with the -d option (https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/logging.html)

Which results in:

```
[workspace] $ cmd.exe /C '""C:\Program Files\Android\Android  Studio\gradle\gradle-2.4\bin\gradle.bat" -d test && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%"'
10:22:31.158 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.nativeintegration.services.NativeServices] Native-platform posix files is not available.  Continuing with fallback.
10:22:32.485 [INFO] [org.gradle.BuildLogger] Starting Build
10:22:32.489 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.BuildLogger] Gradle user home: C:\Users\Beheerder\.gradle
10:22:32.489 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.BuildLogger] Current dir: C:\Users\Beheerder\.jenkins\jobs\Planning library\branches\appointmentClassAndTests\workspace
10:22:32.490 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.BuildLogger] Settings file: null
10:22:32.491 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.BuildLogger] Build file: null
10:22:32.563 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.initialization.buildsrc.BuildSourceBuilder] Starting to build the build sources.
10:22:32.565 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.initialization.buildsrc.BuildSourceBuilder] Gradle source dir does not exist. We leave.
10:22:32.568 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradlePropertiesLoader] Found env project properties: []
10:22:32.569 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradlePropertiesLoader] Found system project properties: []
10:22:32.794 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.mvnsettings.DefaultLocalMavenRepositoryLocator] No local repository in Settings file defined. Using default path: C:\Users\Beheerder\.m2\repository
10:22:33.206 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.initialization.ScriptEvaluatingSettingsProcessor] Timing: Processing settings took: 0.636 secs
10:22:33.210 [INFO] [org.gradle.BuildLogger] Settings evaluated using settings file 'C:\master\settings.gradle'.
10:22:33.419 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Transitioning model element 'tasks' from state Known to Created
10:22:33.420 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Creating tasks using Project.<init>.tasks()
10:22:33.442 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.initialization.ProjectPropertySettingBuildLoader] Looking for project properties from: C:\Users\Beheerder\.jenkins\jobs\Planning library\branches\appointmentClassAndTests\workspace\gradle.properties
10:22:33.445 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.initialization.ProjectPropertySettingBuildLoader] project property file does not exists. We continue!
10:22:33.448 [INFO] [org.gradle.BuildLogger] Projects loaded. Root project using build file 'C:\Users\Beheerder\.jenkins\jobs\Planning library\branches\appointmentClassAndTests\workspace\build.gradle'.
10:22:33.449 [INFO] [org.gradle.BuildLogger] Included projects: [root project 'workspace']
10:22:33.611 [INFO] [org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor] Evaluating root project 'workspace' using build file 'C:\Users\Beheerder\.jenkins\jobs\Planning library\branches\appointmentClassAndTests\workspace\build.gradle'.
10:22:33.644 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface Software Loopback Interface 1
10:22:33.645 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? true
10:22:33.646 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
10:22:33.647 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback address /127.0.0.1
10:22:33.648 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback address /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
10:22:33.648 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface Software Loopback Interface 1
10:22:33.648 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface Intel(R) 82567LM-3 Gigabit Network Connection
10:22:33.649 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
10:22:33.650 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
10:22:33.651 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding remote address /192.168.0.97
10:22:33.651 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding remote address /fe80:0:0:0:f8fc:58a6:6a00:ad3c%eth0
10:22:33.652 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding remote multicast interface Intel(R) 82567LM-3 Gigabit Network Connection
10:22:33.652 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface WAN Miniport (IKEv2)
10:22:33.653 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
10:22:33.654 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
10:22:33.654 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface WAN Miniport (IKEv2)
10:22:33.654 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface WAN Miniport (PPPOE)
10:22:33.656 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
10:22:33.657 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
10:22:33.657 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface WAN Miniport (PPPOE)
10:22:33.657 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface WAN Miniport (IP)
10:22:33.658 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
10:22:33.659 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
10:22:33.659 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface WAN Miniport (IP)
10:22:33.660 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface WAN Miniport (L2TP)
10:22:33.661 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
10:22:33.661 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
10:22:33.662 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface WAN Miniport (L2TP)
10:22:33.662 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
10:22:33.664 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
10:22:33.665 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? false
10:22:33.665 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding remote address /fe80:0:0:0:0:5efe:c0a8:61%net2
10:22:33.665 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface Netwerkadapter voor Microsoft Kernel-foutopsporing
10:22:33.666 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
10:22:33.667 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
10:22:33.667 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface Netwerkadapter voor Microsoft Kernel-foutopsporing
10:22:33.667 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface WAN Miniport (IPv6)
10:22:33.668 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
10:22:33.669 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
10:22:33.669 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface WAN Miniport (IPv6)
10:22:33.670 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface WAN Miniport (Network Monitor)
10:22:33.676 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
10:22:33.677 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
10:22:33.678 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface WAN Miniport (Network Monitor)
10:22:33.678 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface RAS Async Adapter
10:22:33.680 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
10:22:33.681 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
10:22:33.682 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface RAS Async Adapter
10:22:33.682 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
10:22:33.682 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
10:22:33.683 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
10:22:33.683 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
10:22:33.683 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface WAN Miniport (PPTP)
10:22:33.684 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
10:22:33.685 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
10:22:33.686 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface WAN Miniport (PPTP)
10:22:33.687 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface WAN Miniport (SSTP)
10:22:33.690 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
10:22:33.690 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
10:22:33.691 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface WAN Miniport (SSTP)
10:22:33.691 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface Intel(R) 82567LM-3 Gigabit Network Connection-WFP Native MAC Layer LightWeight Filter-0000
10:22:33.692 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
10:22:33.693 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
10:22:33.693 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface Intel(R) 82567LM-3 Gigabit Network Connection-WFP Native MAC Layer LightWeight Filter-0000
10:22:33.693 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface Intel(R) 82567LM-3 Gigabit Network Connection-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000
10:22:33.695 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
10:22:33.696 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
10:22:33.697 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface Intel(R) 82567LM-3 Gigabit Network Connection-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000
10:22:33.697 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface Intel(R) 82567LM-3 Gigabit Network Connection-WFP 802.3 MAC Layer LightWeight Filter-0000
10:22:33.698 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
10:22:33.698 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
10:22:33.698 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface Intel(R) 82567LM-3 Gigabit Network Connection-WFP 802.3 MAC Layer LightWeight Filter-0000
10:22:33.713 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on buildscript class cache for build file 'C:\Users\Beheerder\.jenkins\jobs\Planning library\branches\appointmentClassAndTests\workspace\build.gradle' (C:\Users\Beheerder\.gradle\caches\2.4\scripts\build_1pxgds8pq1zzj1t7lr0294yep\ProjectScript\buildscript).
10:22:33.721 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
10:22:33.853 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on no_buildscript class cache for build file 'C:\Users\Beheerder\.jenkins\jobs\Planning library\branches\appointmentClassAndTests\workspace\build.gradle' (C:\Users\Beheerder\.gradle\caches\2.4\scripts\build_1pxgds8pq1zzj1t7lr0294yep\ProjectScript\no_buildscript).
10:22:33.857 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
10:22:34.854 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Transitioning model element 'tasks.check' from state Known to GraphClosed
10:22:34.857 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Transitioning model element 'tasks.__instantiator' from state Known to GraphClosed
10:22:34.857 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Creating tasks.__instantiator using Project.<init>.tasks.__instantiator()
10:22:34.859 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Finished transitioning model element tasks.__instantiator from state Known to GraphClosed
10:22:34.860 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Transitioning model element 'tasks.__instantiator' from state GraphClosed to GraphClosed
10:22:34.861 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Creating tasks.check using tasks.addPlaceholderAction(check)
10:22:34.862 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Finished transitioning model element tasks.check from state Known to GraphClosed
10:22:34.863 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Transitioning model element 'tasks.check' from state GraphClosed to GraphClosed
10:22:37.064 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor] Timing: Running the build script took 3.453 secs
10:22:37.069 [INFO] [org.gradle.BuildLogger] All projects evaluated.
10:22:37.294 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Transitioning model element 'tasks' from state Created to SelfClosed
10:22:37.296 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Transitioning model element 'binaries' from state Known to GraphClosed
10:22:37.296 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Creating binaries using org.gradle.language.base.plugins.LanguageBasePlugin.apply()
10:22:37.296 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Mutating binaries using org.gradle.language.base.plugins.LanguageBasePlugin.apply()
10:22:37.309 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Transitioning model element 'binaries.__instantiator' from state Known to GraphClosed
10:22:37.309 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Creating binaries.__instantiator using 
10:22:41.252 [INFO] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Successfully started process 'Gradle Test Executor 1'
10:22:42.093 [QUIET] [system.out] 10:22:42.062 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.TcpOutgoingConnector] Attempting to connect to [d1b88604-9e30-4756-8daa-f5c4abd4d39f port:16608, addresses:[/127.0.0.1, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]].
10:22:42.097 [QUIET] [system.out] 10:22:42.095 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.TcpOutgoingConnector] Trying to connect to address /127.0.0.1.
10:22:42.108 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.TcpIncomingConnector] Accepted connection from /127.0.0.1:16609 to /127.0.0.1:16608.
10:22:42.116 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultWorkerProcess] Received connection org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection@5b0b70ee from Gradle Test Executor 1
10:22:42.120 [QUIET] [system.out] 10:22:42.119 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.TcpOutgoingConnector] Connected to address /127.0.0.1:16608.
10:22:42.837 [QUIET] [system.out] 10:22:42.194 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.child.ActionExecutionWorker] Starting Gradle Test Executor 1.
10:22:42.849 [QUIET] [system.out] 10:22:42.264 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker] Gradle Test Executor 1 started executing tests.
10:22:42.931 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] 
10:22:42.933 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] Gradle Test Executor 1 STARTED
10:22:42.934 [QUIET] [system.out] 10:22:42.934 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor] Executing test class nl.buroboot.danielvandenberg.junittest.AppointmentLocationTest
10:22:42.935 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] 
10:22:42.935 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] nl.buroboot.danielvandenberg.junittest.AppointmentLocationTest STARTED
10:22:43.074 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] 
10:22:43.074 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] nl.buroboot.danielvandenberg.junittest.AppointmentLocationTest > test STARTED
10:22:43.077 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] 
10:22:43.077 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] nl.buroboot.danielvandenberg.junittest.AppointmentLocationTest > test PASSED
10:22:43.078 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] 
10:22:43.079 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] nl.buroboot.danielvandenberg.junittest.AppointmentLocationTest PASSED
10:22:43.079 [QUIET] [system.out] 10:22:43.079 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor] Executing test class nl.buroboot.danielvandenberg.junittest.AppointmentStatusTest
10:22:43.080 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] 
10:22:43.080 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] nl.buroboot.danielvandenberg.junittest.AppointmentStatusTest STARTED
10:22:43.083 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] 
10:22:43.083 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] nl.buroboot.danielvandenberg.junittest.AppointmentStatusTest > test STARTED
10:22:43.085 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] 
10:22:43.085 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] nl.buroboot.danielvandenberg.junittest.AppointmentStatusTest > test PASSED
10:22:43.086 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] 
10:22:43.086 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] nl.buroboot.danielvandenberg.junittest.AppointmentStatusTest PASSED
10:22:43.087 [QUIET] [system.out] 10:22:43.087 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor] Executing test class nl.buroboot.danielvandenberg.junittest.AppointmentTest
10:22:43.088 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] 
10:22:43.088 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] nl.buroboot.danielvandenberg.junittest.AppointmentTest STARTED
10:22:43.112 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] 
10:22:43.112 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] nl.buroboot.danielvandenberg.junittest.AppointmentTest > test STARTED
10:22:43.117 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] 
10:22:43.117 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] nl.buroboot.danielvandenberg.junittest.AppointmentTest > test STANDARD_ERROR
10:22:43.119 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     5 [Test worker] WARN nl.buroboot.danielvandenberg.junittest.AppointmentTest - Unimplemented method move
10:22:43.120 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     10 [Test worker] WARN nl.buroboot.danielvandenberg.junittest.AppointmentTest - Unimplemented method requestMove
10:22:43.121 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     10 [Test worker] WARN nl.buroboot.danielvandenberg.junittest.AppointmentTest - Unimplemented method setFulfilled
10:22:43.122 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     12 [Test worker] WARN nl.buroboot.danielvandenberg.junittest.AppointmentTest - Unimplemented method setFailed
10:22:43.123 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     12 [Test worker] WARN nl.buroboot.danielvandenberg.junittest.AppointmentTest - Unimplemented method equals
10:22:43.124 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] 
10:22:43.124 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] nl.buroboot.danielvandenberg.junittest.AppointmentTest > test PASSED
10:22:43.124 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] 
10:22:43.124 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] nl.buroboot.danielvandenberg.junittest.AppointmentTest PASSED
10:22:43.126 [QUIET] [system.out] 10:22:43.125 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker] Gradle Test Executor 1 finished executing tests.
10:22:43.129 [QUIET] [system.out] 10:22:43.129 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.child.ActionExecutionWorker] Completed Gradle Test Executor 1.
10:22:43.131 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] 
10:22:43.131 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] Gradle Test Executor 1 PASSED
10:22:43.136 [QUIET] [system.out] 10:22:43.135 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.child.ActionExecutionWorker] Stopping client connection.
10:22:43.204 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Changing state to: SUCCEEDED
10:22:43.205 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Process 'Gradle Test Executor 1' finished with exit value 0 (state: SUCCEEDED)
10:22:43.212 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] 
10:22:43.212 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] Gradle Test Run :test PASSED
10:22:43.271 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.result.Binary2JUnitXmlReportGenerator] Finished generating test XML results (0.022 secs) into: C:\Users\Beheerder\.jenkins\jobs\Planning library\branches\appointmentClassAndTests\workspace\build\test-results
10:22:43.272 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.report.DefaultTestReport] Generating HTML test report...
10:22:43.336 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.report.DefaultTestReport] Finished generating test html results (0.063 secs) into: C:\Users\Beheerder\.jenkins\jobs\Planning library\branches\appointmentClassAndTests\workspace\build\reports\tests
10:22:43.381 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Finished executing task ':test'
10:22:43.381 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] :test (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 2.955 secs.
10:22:43.382 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] Task worker [Thread[main,5,main]] finished, busy: 5.906 secs, idle: 0.005 secs
10:22:43.382 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter] Timing: Executing the DAG took 5.939 secs
10:22:43.382 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] 
10:22:43.382 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
10:22:43.383 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] 
10:22:43.383 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] Total time: 13.037 secs
10:22:43.384 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.daemon.CompilerDaemonManager] Stopping 0 compiler daemon(s).
10:22:43.384 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.daemon.CompilerDaemonManager] Stopped 0 compiler daemon(s).
10:22:43.390 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on cache directory workerMain (C:\Users\Beheerder\.gradle\caches\2.4\workerMain).
10:22:43.391 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on buildscript class cache for build file 'C:\Users\Beheerder\.jenkins\jobs\Planning library\branches\appointmentClassAndTests\workspace\build.gradle' (C:\Users\Beheerder\.gradle\caches\2.4\scripts\build_1pxgds8pq1zzj1t7lr0294yep\ProjectScript\buildscript).
10:22:43.394 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on no_buildscript class cache for build file 'C:\Users\Beheerder\.jenkins\jobs\Planning library\branches\appointmentClassAndTests\workspace\build.gradle' (C:\Users\Beheerder\.gradle\caches\2.4\scripts\build_1pxgds8pq1zzj1t7lr0294yep\ProjectScript\no_buildscript).
10:22:43.395 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache module-metadata.bin (C:\Users\Beheerder\.gradle\caches\modules-2\metadata-2.15\module-metadata.bin)
10:22:43.395 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache artifact-at-repository.bin (C:\Users\Beheerder\.gradle\caches\modules-2\metadata-2.15\artifact-at-repository.bin)
10:22:43.395 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on artifact cache (C:\Users\Beheerder\.gradle\caches\modules-2).
10:22:43.412 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess] Cache Plugin Resolution Cache (C:\Users\Beheerder\.gradle\caches\2.4\plugin-resolution) was closed 0 times.
10:22:43.413 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache fileSnapshots.bin (C:\Users\Beheerder\.jenkins\jobs\Planning library\branches\appointmentClassAndTests\workspace\.gradle\2.4\taskArtifacts\fileSnapshots.bin)
10:22:43.416 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache fileHashes.bin (C:\Users\Beheerder\.jenkins\jobs\Planning library\branches\appointmentClassAndTests\workspace\.gradle\2.4\taskArtifacts\fileHashes.bin)
10:22:43.425 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache outputFileStates.bin (C:\Users\Beheerder\.jenkins\jobs\Planning library\branches\appointmentClassAndTests\workspace\.gradle\2.4\taskArtifacts\outputFileStates.bin)
10:22:43.425 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache taskArtifacts.bin (C:\Users\Beheerder\.jenkins\jobs\Planning library\branches\appointmentClassAndTests\workspace\.gradle\2.4\taskArtifacts\taskArtifacts.bin)
10:22:43.428 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on task history cache (C:\Users\Beheerder\.jenkins\jobs\Planning library\branches\appointmentClassAndTests\workspace\.gradle\2.4\taskArtifacts).
10:22:43.433 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.store.CachedStoreFactory] Resolution result cache closed. Cache reads: 0, disk reads: 0 (avg: 0.0 secs, total: 0.0 secs)
10:22:43.434 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.store.CachedStoreFactory] Resolved configuration cache closed. Cache reads: 0, disk reads: 0 (avg: 0.0 secs, total: 0.0 secs)
10:22:43.434 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.store.ResolutionResultsStoreFactory] Deleted 2 resolution results binary files in 0.004 secs
10:22:43.434 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.memcache.InMemoryCachedRepositoryFactory] In-memory dependency metadata cache closed. Repos cached: 3, cache instances: 1, modules served from cache: 4, artifacts: 4
Build step 'Invoke Gradle script' changed build result to SUCCESS
```

And that's not even half the log. Now somewhere in there is the following:

```
10:22:43.117 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] nl.buroboot.danielvandenberg.junittest.AppointmentTest > test STANDARD_ERROR
10:22:43.119 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     5 [Test worker] WARN nl.buroboot.danielvandenberg.junittest.AppointmentTest - Unimplemented method move
10:22:43.120 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     10 [Test worker] WARN nl.buroboot.danielvandenberg.junittest.AppointmentTest - Unimplemented method requestMove
10:22:43.121 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     10 [Test worker] WARN nl.buroboot.danielvandenberg.junittest.AppointmentTest - Unimplemented method setFulfilled
10:22:43.122 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     12 [Test worker] WARN nl.buroboot.danielvandenberg.junittest.AppointmentTest - Unimplemented method setFailed
10:22:43.123 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     12 [Test worker] WARN nl.buroboot.danielvandenberg.junittest.AppointmentTest - Unimplemented method equals
```

This part is actually useful. But I don't want to have to scan through all that code to find those parts. Now my question is, is there a way to let gradle filter out only the messages containing the tag `[TestEventLogger]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I figured it out. You just shouldn't use the -d option. Only supplying

```
test {
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
}
```

is enough to show logs. Hope this helps others running into the same problem.